# Not getting output using flutter

Tags: flutter

I am writing code to generate user form using Flutter. Following is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const RadioListTileApp());

class RadioListTileApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const RadioListTileApp({super.key});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('User Profile')),
        body: const RadioListTileExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum SingingCharacter {Male, Female}


class RadioListTileExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const RadioListTileExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<RadioListTileExample> createState() => _RadioListTileExampleState();
}

class _RadioListTileExampleState extends State<RadioListTileExample> {
  SingingCharacter? _character = SingingCharacter.Male;
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListView( 
                    Container( 
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Name',
            ),
          ),
        ),

        Container(
        Text("Gender"),
        RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
          title: const Text('Male'),
          value: SingingCharacter.Male,
          groupValue: _character,
          onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
            setState(() {
              _character = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
          title: const Text('Female'),
          value: SingingCharacter.Female,
          groupValue: _character,
          onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
            setState(() {
              _character = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

On my output screen, I am able to see only "User Profile" text. Fields such as "Name" and "Gender" are missing.

Comment: that code doesn't even compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i don't know how your code run successfully as i am able to see many things missing like `child` key in `ListView` and `Container` and also many childs are written within `Container` with `Column` and also don't need to use `ListView` to make your screen scrollable for form . You can use `SingleChildViewScroll` . Try with below mention code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const RadioListTileApp());

class RadioListTileApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const RadioListTileApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('User Profile')),
        body: const RadioListTileExample(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum SingingCharacter { Male, Female }

class RadioListTileExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const RadioListTileExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<RadioListTileExample> createState() => _RadioListTileExampleState();
}

class _RadioListTileExampleState extends State<RadioListTileExample> {
  SingingCharacter? _character = SingingCharacter.Male;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            hintText: 'Name',
          ),
        ),
        Text("Gender"),
        RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
          title: const Text('Male'),
          value: SingingCharacter.Male,
          groupValue: _character,
          onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
            setState(() {
              _character = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
          title: const Text('Female'),
          value: SingingCharacter.Female,
          groupValue: _character,
          onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
            setState(() {
              _character = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Apologies @Shweta but it is suggested to do some research and code before you ask anything here ... and before you go with that , it is better you understand how you can place your code https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/widgets/layout#:~:text=Single%2Dchild%20layout%20widgets,-Align&text=A%20widget%20that%20aligns%20its,based%20on%20the%20child%27s%20size.&text=A%20widget%20that%20attempts%20to,to%20a%20specific%20aspect%20ratio.&text=Container%20that%20positions%20its%20child%20according%20to%20the%20child%27s%20baseline.&text=Alignment%20block%20that%20centers%20its%20child%20within%20itself.